# Get USER tagged and saved videos by graph api

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

**I have two queries;**

**1-** How can i get user's tagged videos as the below request to Graph API returns me nil on request :( and i have spend about thousands of minutes on searching for this issue but did not find the accurate answer or reason of this issue.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"me/videos/tagged"
                                  parameters:nil
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        //         Insert your code here

    NSLog(@"Result is:%@",result);

}];
```

**2-** How to make a call for user's saved videos on Facebook to Graph API?

I am Running FB SDK Version 4.20.2 and Graph API version 2.9.

Currently I am using a test account for this purpose and all videos are public.

Comment: Does your app have the necessary permission from the user to read their videos?

Comment: Yes of course it has. As i mentioned above the account is test and all permission are allowed at login time. Account has tagged videos which are public.
You mean i have to get permission from friends who are tagged in or something like that?

Comment: @CBroe, Now the result from Graph API is coming empty instead of nil. What you think why is data not coming?

Comment: I’d always recommend to test such requests in Graph API Explorer first, before you do any coding. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Right, I tried it also. As per Facebook Graph documentation, <me/videos?type=tagged> should returned me user's tagged video then why Graph API Explorer did not give me tagged videos :( ??

Comment: Did you use your own app id in GAE? What permissions did you grant? Does it show any debug messages?

Comment: Yes i did used my app id by <*APP ID*/permissions>. All permissions including <user_tagged_places> status is granted in GAE debugger.

Comment: I am pretty sure that should require `user_videos` permission from the person who published the video.

Comment: how could a get < user_videos > permission from that person?
suppose, tagged videos from different friends have been updating in future then I have to make request for permission every time a different friend tagged me?

Comment: Well first of all you should test if that is actually the case. (Add a friend who tagged you in one of their videos as a tester to the app, and then see if you get a result if they grant the permission to your app.) But since other endpoints, such as f.e. sharedposts, work the same way - return only posts that are “visible” to the app, i.e. the app has permission from the person who made the post - I think it is likely that this is the case here, too.

Comment: I followed your instructions as exactly: I have added a tester to app; login my App using this tester account; allowed permissions by tester who made the tagged post; came to GAE debugger and tried to fetch the tagged videos but result is still empty :( now what could be the reason?
totally fed up around the issue whats going on.

Comment: Sorry, don’t know. You can file a bug report and ask them to clarify, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: right @CBroe,  Is it possible to get user's saved videos by GAE?
thanks for you support.